# Are there any ways to add Bootstrap Carousel in CKEditor (django-ckeditor)

Tags: django, ckeditor, bootstrap-5, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor

I want to make feature for admin in my django site to add bootstrap carousels (or just carousels) to show images in CKEditor `RichTextUploadingField` field on my model instanses. What is the better way to implement that thing? Maybe there are **ready-made** solutions?

---

I heard about [bootstrapCarousel](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/bootstrapCarousel) plugin, but maybe it is deprecated, although it supports Bootstrap 4.